# Remove string with greedy regular expression in QT

Tags: c++, regex, qt

thanks for any help in advance. I'm quite new to qt so please excuse my newbie question.

I want to replace image1="jdjddsj" with "im" with a regular expression in a string. There are more of these partes with xx="..." in my string, so I wanted to run QRegExp greedy, which somehow doesn't seem to work.

```
QString str_commando;

str_commando = "python python.py image1=\"sonstzweiteil\" one! path=\"sonstwas\" image2=\"sonsteinanderes\" two!"

QString str(str_commando); // The initial string.
qDebug() << str_commando.remove(QRegExp ("age1=\"([^>]*)\""));

/* Set field */
ui->lineeCommand->setText(str_commando);
```

Result is unfortunately:
python python.py im two!

```
 qDebug() << str_commando.remove(QRegExp ("age1=\"([^>]*)\""));
```

I have tried it with before. Same result.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for your help in advance!

**SOLUTION:**

```
qDebug() << str_commando.replace(QRegExp ("image1=\"([^\"]*)\""), "im");
```

Comment: Simply use `"age1=\"([^>\"]*)\""`. If you'd like a nongreedy pattern, you may try `"age1=\"([^>]*?)\""` But I don't know if QT supports that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character set `[^>]` includes `"`. This mean the regex in

```
str_commando.remove(QRegExp ("age1=\"([^>]*)\""));
```

matches `age1=\"sonstzweiteil\" one! path=\"sonstwas\" image2=\"sonsteinanderes\"`. If you are sure that there is no `"` between the quotes, you could set the regex *minimal* instead of *greedy*. Another solution would be to set the set `[^>]` to `[^>"]`. I also doesn't know why you are forbidding `>`.

After looking in the documentation of *QString* I think you could also do something like this:

```
str_commando.replace(QRegExp("image1=\"([^\"]|\\\")*\""), "im");
```

or if you want to have `im="..."`:

```
str_commando.replace(QRegExp("image1=\"((?:[^\"]|\\\")*)\""), "im=\"\\1\"");
```

Comment: thanks a ton! you solved it for me!

    qDebug() << str_commando.replace(QRegExp ("image1=\"([^\"]*)\""), "im");
is what I'm using succesfully. I shouldn't just copy'n' paste regular expressions from old projects :)